# Jumbotron animate() doesnt work

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-animate

i've been trying to change the color of the jumbotron using jquery's animate(0 method, But for some reason it isn't working.

```
$('.jumbotron').on('click', function() {
    console.log('click');
    $('.jumbotron').animate({
        backgroundColor: "rgb(229, 76, 76)"
    }, 1000);
    $('body').animate({
        backgroundColor: "#ff7373"
    }, 1000);
});
```

Only works if i use the css selector to change the color. like this,

```
$('#jumbo').on('click', function() {
    $( this ).css('background-color','#e54c4c');
});
```

Anyone knows why?

Comment: `$('.jumbotron').animate({
        background-color: "rgb(229, 76, 76)"
    }, 1000);
    $('body').animate({
        background-color: "#ff7373"
    }, 1000);` try this

Comment: Still doesn't work. @AlivetoDie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties): All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the [jQuery.Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin is used).

So try to include `jquery color` for its proper working.

```js
$('.jumbotron').on('click', function() {
  console.log('click');
  // use this instead of using .jumbotron again
  $(this).animate({
    backgroundColor: "rgb(229, 76, 76)",
  }, 1000);
  $('body').animate({
    backgroundColor: "#ff7373"
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>
    <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
  </div>
  <p>This is some text.</p>
  <p>This is another text.</p>
</div>
```

If you don't want to use any plugin then you can use [transition](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) like,

```js
$('.jumbotron').on('click', function() {
  console.log('click');
  // just toggle highlighted classs
  $(this).add('body').toggleClass('highlighted');
});
```

```css
.jumbotron,body {
  -webkit-transition: background 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: background 1s linear;
  -ms-transition: background 1s linear;
  -o-transition: background 1s linear;
  transition: background 1s linear;
}
body.highlighted{background:#ff7373}
.jumbotron.highlighted{background:rgb(229, 76, 76)}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.2.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Bootstrap Tutorial</h1>
    <p>Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
  </div>
  <p>This is some text.</p>
  <p>This is another text.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: weird, i added the same thing as you did here but it doesnt work for me but works for you . How damn.

Comment: If possible for you, then show me the URL, so that I can help you in finding your issue. Are you using jQuery color plugin?

Comment: Remove Jquery 2.1 from head and add color.js after bootstrap.js

Comment: Good job by you (Are you really on 17). Anyways, you should remove `Jquery 2.*`, it is preferable that there should be only 1 version of jquery included in a web page.

Comment: oh i didn't notice i had 2 libs in it. (Removed) . And yeah i'm 17 :D

Comment: Hey, why is it that when i load the content of the page using ajax.load() method the animate and the rest of the ajax functions linking  them dont work anymore?

[This Link](http://kautilya.ga/2.html) loads the content from portfolio.html and hence the animate no longer works.

Comment: Your jumbotron is dynamically added in DOM, so you need to use event delegation like `$('#content').on('click', '.jumbotron', function() {`

Comment: Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

My friend, according to jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

> Animation Properties and Values
>
> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color plugin is used). Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable.

You need to include https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color after jQuery (and before your script!) in order to be able to animate the **`backgroundColor`** property.

Let me know how it goes ;)